# Installing two versions of MSSQL on a production server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, high-availability, database-mirroring

We've just provisioned a second dedicated server so we can use database mirroring for high availability.

The existing server uses MSSQL Express 2005. We have MSSQL Web 2008 and want to minimise the downtime to get mirroring set up. Can I install MSSQL Web 2008 while the production server still runs without any conflicts?

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

PS these boxes run IIS + MSSQL and I'm setting up NLB too, although thats another post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use Named Instances, but yes you can do this easilly. We have a server running SQL 2005 Express, 2008 Express and 2008 R2 Standard all happily.

Comment: Thanks. The current 2005 Express is not using a named instance, ie we connect to "SERVERNAME", so just specify a named instance during the installation? Won't have to take the server down or anyting?

Comment: @Tom - correct, just enter an instance name when you install the next version of SQL and they will live quite happily. No need to take server down, reboot anything or restart any services.

Comment: Fantastic. So the downtime would be detaching the db's from Express 2005, attaching them to 2008 and setting up the mirroring?

Comment: If you're installing a named instance of SQL Server 2005 Express, you need to select the Advanced installation options during the install. If you don't, a default instance will be installed.

Comment: @joeqwerty SQL Express is already on the server, putting on SQL 2008 (i guess as a named instance so it will live happily beside the existing SQL Express)

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry, I misread your post. Carry on. ;)

Comment: @Tom - correct :)